# Python Driver Cassandra query Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra

I am having issues while querying my cassandra database through python driver.

My cassandra version is 
python2.7

```
>>> import cassandra
>>> cassandra.__version__
'2.1.3'
>>>
```

My code:

```
def search_data(self, ticker):
      row = self.session.execute("""select * from secmaster.ticker_name where ticker = %s""",(ticker))
      print row
```

Getting error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1293, in execute
    future = self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1342, in execute_async
    future = self._create_response_future(query, parameters, trace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1373, in _create_response_future
    query_string = bind_params(query_string, parameters, self.encoder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/query.py", line 727, in bind_params
    return query % tuple(encoder.cql_encode_all_types(v) for v in params)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

But if i do below query it does work

```
 def search_data(self, ticker):
          row = self.session.execute("""select * from secmaster.ticker_name""")
          print row
```

Answer (score 3):

`Session.execute`'s parameter `parameters` must be called with a sequence (such as a `tuple`) or a `dict`. Note that just enclosing a single expression in parentheses does not make it a one-item tuple; you must add a trailing comma, e.g.:

```
def search_data(self, ticker):
      row = self.session.execute("""select * from secmaster.ticker_name where ticker = %s""",(ticker,))
      print row
```

Answer (score -3):

Fixed

row = self.session.execute("select * from secmaster.ticker_name where ticker='%s'"% ticker)

Comment: You should look into using prepared statements which are much more efficient.

Comment: Inserting parameters in database queries with string substitution leads to database injection vulnerabilities